# Simple shell script that creates a dir with a random name

Tags: shell, create-directory

I'm trying to write a simple shell script in linux that creates directories with random names.

The names must be made from the date of the day followed by a random string 
like in this example:
2018-02-22y2Fdv9zzLVLupkl9El0dWalJAGTROLxE

This is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
# the date
DATAOGGI= echo -n $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
# random string
RANDOM_STRING=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
# the dir
NEW_DIR=$(echo -n ${DATAOGGI}${RANDOM_STRING})
echo $NEW_DIR
mkdir $NEW_DIR
```

Unfortunately, even if the variable NEW_DIR is correct 
    echo $NEW_DIR -> 2018-02-22y2Fdv9zzLVLupkl9El0dWalJAGTROLxE

the name of the directory is
    y2Fdv9zzLVLupkl9El0dWalJAGTROLxE

Comment: there should be no space  during variable assignment `DATAOGGI=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")` and `echo` is unwarranted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try just:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATAOGGI=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
RANDOM_STRING=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
mkdir "${DATAOGGI}${RANDOM_STRING}"
```

apart from fact that it is not necessary in this example `echo -n` AFAIK has very inconsistent behavior and it is advised to use `printf` instead